# webpack-dev-server runs out of memory doing react development in dev container

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vscode-devcontainer

I am developing a react application inside of a vscode dev container and the development server keeps crashing with the following message:

```
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
```

I also noticed a deprecation warning on the dev server that I thought might be related:

[image]

I am not sure if the problem here is an issue with webpack (maybe related to the deprecation warning) or if somehow the container has limited resources and I just need to allocate more memory for it? I'm feeling very much out of my depth here. Any help would be much appreciated.

devcontainer.json:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.231.6/containers/javascript-node
{
    "name": "Node.js",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        // Update 'VARIANT' to pick a Node version: 16, 14, 12.
        // Append -bullseye or -buster to pin to an OS version.
        // Use -bullseye variants on local arm64/Apple Silicon.
        "args": { "VARIANT": "16-bullseye" }
    },

    // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {},

    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
    ],

    // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
    // "forwardPorts": [],

    // Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
    // "postCreateCommand": "yarn install",

    // Comment out to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
    "remoteUser": "node"
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# See here for image contents: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.231.6/containers/javascript-node/.devcontainer/base.Dockerfile

# [Choice] Node.js version (use -bullseye variants on local arm64/Apple Silicon): 16, 14, 12, 16-bullseye, 14-bullseye, 12-bullseye, 16-buster, 14-buster, 12-buster
ARG VARIANT="16-bullseye"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-${VARIANT}

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
# RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
#     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends <your-package-list-here>

# [Optional] Uncomment if you want to install an additional version of node using nvm
# ARG EXTRA_NODE_VERSION=10
# RUN su node -c "source /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install ${EXTRA_NODE_VERSION}"

# [Optional] Uncomment if you want to install more global node modules
# RUN su node -c "npm install -g <your-package-list-here>"
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "some project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-detect-click-outside": "^1.1.7",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: No details of your setup? devcontainer.json? and package.json?

Comment: @ikhvjs Sorry for the delay adding this info. I just resorted to developing without a container temporarily.